# exception throw: dependent-name is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type

Tags: c++, templates, throw

I have a template Matrix class:

```
template <typename T, int row, int col>
class Matrix{};
```

Inside the class decleration I wrote an execption class, based on std::exception:

```
class MatrixException: public std::exception
{
private:
    const char* errmsg;
public:
    MatrixException(const char* msg="")
        :errmsg(msg) {} 
    const char* what() const noexcept {return errmsg;}
};

class IllegalOperation: public MatrixException
{
    public:
        IllegalOperation(const char* msg="")
            : MatrixException(msg) {}
};
```

I tried to use it on one of the non-class' functions, in the implantation part, like this:

```
template <typename T, int row1, int col1, int row2, int col2>
Matrix<T, row1, col2> operator*(const Matrix<T, row1, col1>& mat1, const Matrix<T, row2, col2>& mat2)
{
    if (condition)
        throw Matrix<T, row2, col2>::IllegalOperation("message");
    // do stuff
    return res;
}
```

I got a warning:

`In instantiation of 'Matrix<T, row1, col2> operator*(const Matrix<T, row, col>&, const Matrix<T, row2, col2>&) [with T = int; int row1 = 3; int col1 = 3; int row2 = 3; int col2 = 2]': required from here`

And this error message:

`dependent-name 'Matrix<T, row, col>::IllegalOperation' is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type`

How can I fix this?

I've looked here:
[Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)
and then tried to add the word `template` here and there, but it didn't work.

Comment: `throw typename Matrix<T, row2, col2>:::IllegalOperation` https://godbolt.org/z/6rWMv676f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `typename` keyword to the `throw` expression.

```
 if (condition)
        throw typename Matrix<T, row2, col2>::IllegalOperation("message");
    // do stuff
```

As stated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#:%7E:text=names%20(see%20above)-,The,typedef%20declaration%20or%20by%20being%20used%20to%20name%20a%20base%20class.,-Run%20this%20code)

> In a declaration or a definition of a template, including alias template, a name that is not a member of the current instantiation and is dependent on a template parameter is not considered to be a type unless the keyword typename is used or unless it was already established as a type name, e.g. with a typedef declaration or by being used to name a base class.

Hence `IllegalOperation` in this case is not considered to by a type, but rather is considered probably as a function.

Comment: Thanks! I seem to got confused between "template" and "typename".